# Loading Training Data in Keras, Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gpu

I am using a large machine to load my complete dataset into memory for training with the following method: (Using my generator to load the whole data into a x and y tensor)

```
training_generator = my_generator(train_data_file, batch_size=TOTAL_SAMPLES)
x_tensor, y_tensor = training_generator.__getitem__(0)
```

I am doing so in order to train faster without using a generator during training. I have plenty of RAM to load this dataset, but I get the following error. I am not sure why my GPU is being used at the point in loading the data. How can I change my method to not overuse the GPU memory? Below is my **getitem** function, then the traceback.

```
from tensorflow import cast, float16
    def __getitem__(self, idx) :
        """
        Function for tensorflow to get a Batch of Data
        return batch_x:
        return batch_y:
        """
        # X Data
        x_list = []
        # Y Data
        y_list = []
        # Loop Through Batch
        for i in range(0, self.batch_size):
            x_list.append(cast(self.h5_data[self.batches[idx][i]]['x'][:], dtype=float16))
            df = pd.DataFrame(data=self.h5_data[self.batches[idx][i]]['y'][:])
            y_list.append(cast(convert_dataframe_to_tensor(df),dtype=float16))

        # Stack X List into Tensor
        batch_x = np.stack(x_list, axis=0)
        # Stack Y List into Tensor
        batch_y = np.stack(y_list, axis=0)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ae34a7e4c3fd> in <module>
     30
---> 31     x_tensor, y_tensor = training_generator.__getitem__(0)
     32 
     33     

~/thirdeye/lib/generators.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
     71             df = pd.DataFrame(data=self.h5_data[self.batches[idx][i]]['y'][:])
     72             
---> 73             y_list.append(cast(convert_dataframe_to_tensor(df),dtype=float16))                                 
     74 
     75         # Stack X List into Tensor

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    178     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    179     try:
--> 180       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    181     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    182       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py in cast(x, dtype, name)
    705       x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, name="x")
    706       if x.dtype.base_dtype != base_type:
--> 707         x = gen_math_ops.cast(x, base_type, name=name)
    708     if x.dtype.is_complex and base_type.is_floating:
    709       logging.warn("Casting complex to real discards imaginary part.")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in cast(x, DstT, Truncate, name)
   1969         pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
   1970     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 1971       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   1972   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
   1973   DstT = _execute.make_type(DstT, "DstT")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6604   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6605   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6606   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6607   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6608 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run Cast: Dst tensor is not initialized. [Op:Cast] name: Cast/
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory consumed on GPU is a sum of trainable parameters in the network (for instance 300MB for VGG19), floating point type (FP16 or FP32), number of activations and size of the images you are feeding and batch size. So when we have 100GB of dataset in our RAM (in our computers RAM not GPUs), we use a batch of it to train the networks then take another batch since all it can't fit into GPU Memory (Which is 11GB for consumer grade RTX2080Ti).

Your `training_generator = my_generator(train_data_file, batch_size=TOTAL_SAMPLES)` have `batch_size` defined as `TOTAL_SAMPLES` which I guess means total number of samples in your database. So there is no way you can fit your 100 GB database into 11GB ram. Try to start from 32 and increment with multiples of 32 until you get an OOM error.

Comment: I see - however, my model.fit function (which I should have included) has a batch size of 16 currently. I think the problem is that in my generator, I am using tf functions (cast) which may be harnessing the GPU. I removed these and am still getting an OOM error, but later on in the script now.